# Enumerating programs as graphs, or executing graphs?

Tags: graphs, programming-languages

Both programs and simple graphs can be enumerated using natural numbers (positive integers).

However, *what languages or ideas most naturally combine the two?*

For example enumerating programs using graphs instead of natural numbers.

Or executing graphs, in other words code described by a graphs shape instead of by text, and not just for tree shaped graphs.

Comment: Would state machines count? A state machine is a (very limited) program and it's also a graph (where edge labels are important).

Comment: Good thinking, but if this is a Finite State Machine, I'm not sure thats a program as such, although maybe with some context of how to make it so it might be. However there would likely be more involved in the definition of a program than shape of a graph, such as values at the nodes.

Comment: You assume that every two countable sets are connected by a "meaningful" translation. This is (sorry) absurd. The set of all humans and the set of pens on my desk are both countable but (arguably) not related at all.

Answer (score 1):

We can summarize your original findings as follows: there is an effective enumeration for programs and graphs. An effective enumeration of a countable set $S$ is a computable bijection between the natural numbers and $S$, that is, a program $P(n)$ such that $S = \{ P(n) : n \geq 0 \}$ and $P(n) \neq P(m)$ for $n \neq m$.

There are many countable sets which can be effectively enumerated – there is nothing special about programs and graphs. We can generalize and say that if $S_1,S_2$ can be effectively enumerated, then there is a computable bijection between $S_1$ and $S_2$ (why?), but this doesn't say much about any relation between $S_1$ and $S_2$.